# No ACK with i2c Write slave adress to TCA9555

Tags: i2c

Running a test on a PIC16F18877 I encounter a problem with i2cWrite.

During sending an adress to a TCA9555 i can not get a proper ACK.
   After I2c start the function is called with slave adress 0x40.
   In fact 0x20 first 7 bits for slave adress complemented with 0 for Write
   on bit 0.
   A0;A1 and A2 are all pulled to GND. Testing with a different TCA9555 gives
   the same error.

I need to see ACK becomes 0 but the return value is 1.

The i2cWritefunction has been used in many projects and tested just now 
   with  a DS3231. From this device I get a proper ACK.

Stepping through the function shows the proper SDA high and low signals.
   Even visible on the SDA line itself.

I might be doing something wrong with the TCA9555 but have no idea what.

```
   bit i2cWrite(const unsigned char Byte)
       {
            unsigned char i = 0;
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)        // Repeat for every bit
        {
          Set_SCL_Low;
          Delay();
          // when it is confirm that SCL is low
          if((Byte<<i)&0x80)    // Place data bit value on SDA pin
            Set_SDA_High;   // If bit is high, make SDA high
          else          // Data is transferred MSB first
            Set_SDA_Low;    // If bit is low, make SDA low
          Delay();
          Set_SCL_High;     // So that slave can ackknowldege
          Delay();
          Delay();
         }
         // Get ACK from slave
         Set_SCL_Low;
         Set_SDA_High;
         Delay();
         Delay();
         Set_SCL_High;
         Delay();
         Delay();
         return SDA;
        }
```

Comment: I have to ask: Why are you bit-banging a uC that has hardware support for I2C?  Those delays are making me cringe.  Seems like the hard way...  You had better get out a logic analyzer/scope and save some traces.

Comment: All of this is done for you in section 31 of the datasheet.  However, if you _need_ to bit-bang this interface, please post some traces of scl & sda of the transaction.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen. Since I also use SPI on the same uC i need bit-bang. I will try to create some traces with the , non digital, oscilloscope.

Comment: To debug I2C (and other serial interfaces), it is highly recommended to have a logic analyzer with built-in decoder. Saleae 24MHz 8-ch analyzer clones can be found for $6 - $12 on eBay.

Comment: @AliChen. I ordered one just now

Comment: @Decapod - A logic analyser will be useful, but I would still like to see the "failing" I2C address byte on a 'scope trace. There have been a few times when I have been called to investigate equipment where a logic analyser trace of the interface suggests that everything *should* be working, yet it isn't. When I then use a *scope* and view the analog signals, I can see that there is actually a problem, which is invisible on the *logic analyser* traces (e.g. due to LA having different thresholds than actual signal receiver, or inadequate LA sampling rate etc.). Scope traces are still valuable!

Comment: How long are your delays? I don't think the TCA9555 supports clock stretching.

Comment: Since you didn’t show any initialization routines, I have to ask: are you sure the lines, particularly SDA, are set open-collector?

Comment: @DoxyLover, Yes SDA and SCL both have pull up resistors. On high only TRIS is changed. On low both TRIS and PORT are changed.